# Adding random relationships in Neo4j only uses single node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

My structure looks like this:

```
Person   -[:HAS_HOBBY]->  Hobby
```

I'm generating e.g. 500 person nodes and 20 hobby nodes randomly and would now like to generate random links in between them so that each person has 1 or more hobbies but not every person has the same one.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate("
    match (p:Person),(h:Hobby) with p,h limit 1000 
    where rand() < 0.1 RETURN p,h ", 
    "CREATE (p)-[:HAS_HOBBY]->(h)", 
    {batchSize: 20000, parallel: true}) 
YIELD batches, total 
RETURN *
```

Without the APOC function the query looks like this:

```
MATCH(p:Person),(h:Hobby)
WITH p,h
LIMIT 10000
WHERE rand() < 0.1
CREATE (p)-[:HAS_HOBBY]->(h)
```

This is the query I have tried, the problem is that all the person nodes are all linked to one single hobby node so only 1/20 nodes is being used.

Is there anything missing in my query? Or should I tackle this problem in a different way?

I have also tried different approaches with `FOREACH` clauses looping through all the nodes or using `SKIP` and `LIMIT` through a cartesian product

Thanks a lot!

edit:

[Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56927127/6278182) by InverseFalcon using `apoc.periodic.iterate`:

```
call apoc.periodic.iterate("
// first generate your range of how many hobbies you want a person to have
// for this example, 1 to 5 hobbies
WITH range(1,5) as hobbiesRange
// next get all hobies in a list
MATCH (h:Hobby)
WITH collect(h) as hobbies, hobbiesRange
MATCH (p:Person)
// randomly pick number of hobbies in the range, use that to get a number of random hobbies
WITH p, apoc.coll.randomItems(hobbies, apoc.coll.randomItem(hobbiesRange)) as hobbies
// create relationships
    RETURN p,hobbies", 
"FOREACH (hobby in hobbies | CREATE (p)-[:HAS_HOBBY]->(hobby))", 
{batchSize: 1000, parallel: false});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be easier to not use iterate() in this case, but instead use some of APOC's collection helper functions, such as those used to get random items from a collection. Something like this:

```
// first generate your range of how many hobbies you want a person to have
// for this example, 1 to 5 hobbies
WITH range(1,5) as hobbiesRange
// next get all hobies in a list
MATCH (h:Hobby)
WITH collect(h) as hobbies, hobbiesRange
MATCH (p:Person)
// randomly pick number of hobbies in the range, use that to get a number of random hobbies
WITH p, apoc.coll.randomItems(hobbies, apoc.coll.randomItem(hobbiesRange)) as hobbies
// create relationships
FOREACH (hobby in hobbies | CREATE (p)-[:HAS_HOBBY]->(hobby))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, thank worked very well!
I had to use the query with `apoc.periodic.iterate` though as it could not handle a load of 200.000 person nodes with 10 hobbies. I will post your code wrapped using `apoc.periodic.iterate` in my question

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct except limit it should be 10000 instead of 1000. (Better don't use the limit).
It's working for me and creating nearly 1000 relationships(random Person and Hobby) for 500 Persons and 20 Hobbies.

If you used this to perform this operation in batches then set the batch size to 1000 instead of limit 1000. Your WHERE condition will limit the number of relationships to approx 10% of all the possible combinations of Person and Hobby.
Here 500x20=1000, so there will be approx 1000 relationship.

> NOTE: Using limit 1000 will create relationships only with the first
>   two Hobbies.

For limit 500 only one hobby will be used, for limit 1000 first two, for limit 1500 first 3 and so on (500 is the number of Persons).